# How to return array in php?

Tags: php

How to return array in php ? Actually I want to return whole value of `$x[]` insted of last index of `$x[]`. Please help me...

```
<?php

    function top() {
        require './php/connection.php';
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_add";
        $query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
        $n = 0;
        while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            $a[$n] = $result['add_id'];
            $n = $n + 1;
        }
        $n = $n - 1;
        for ($j = 0; $j < $n; $j++) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $n - 1 - $j; $i++) {
                if ($a[$i] > $a[$i + 1]) {
                    $tmp = $a[$i];
                    $a[$i] = $a[$i + 1];
                    $a[$i + 1] = $tmp;
                }
            }
        }
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $n; $i++) {
            echo $a[$i] . '<br>';
        }
        $j = 1;
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {
            $r = $a[$i];

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_add WHERE add_id='$r'";
            $query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
            $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);
            if ($result) {
                $x[] = $result['mail'];
                return $x[];
            }
        }

    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Return $x ? What happens?

Comment: You cannot use `$x[]` for *reading* in arrays. Instead just do `return $x;`

Comment: If you need to return two values use `return array($x, $y);`

Comment: but I want to store matched value and return that values. So need an array and  have to return those.

Comment: @RokibulHasan read the answers below, it will be an array

Answer (score 2):

`return $x[];` is invalid syntax.

In expression `$x[] = $result['mail'];`, [`$x[]`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.modifying) doesn't mean *"the last element of `$x`"*. It is just a courtesy of PHP that spares the programmer of writing `$x[count($x)]`<sup>1</sup> instead.

Returning an array is as easy as `return $x;` (given `$x` is an [`array`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)).

Btw, there is no place in your code where `$x` is initialized as array. You just add values to some variable that doesn't exist, using the array syntax. PHP helps you and creates an array first and stores it in the `$x` variable but this practice is strongly discouraged. You should add `$x = array();` somewhere before you use `$x` for the first time (outside the loop, of course). For example, you can put it before the line `for ($i = 0; $i <= 5; $i++) {`.
`

---

<sup>1</sup> This statement is not entirely correct. However, if the values are added to the array using only the `$x[] = ...` syntax (as it happens in the posted code) then it is correct.

Comment: Yes values are added only by using $x[ ]; but returns only last index

Answer (score 0):

You have to return `$x`

Then when you call this function `$data = top();`

Now you get return data of function top to variable name `data`

Answer (score 0):

```
// the code below will return $x as it is, independent of what it is. Array, integer, string etc..
Return $x;

// if you need to return two values use:
Return array($x, $y);
// again bit variables are returned as they are.
```

To call the function and get the values/array use:

```
$array = top();
Var_dump($array); //should be $x from your function
```